# How do I install a new light fixture to this old exterior junction box?

Tags: electrical, wiring, exterior, junction-box, old-house

I have a large exterior junction box for front porch 1953 addition. Trying to install a new LED flush mount light fixture. Nowhere to put a metal bar to hold the light fixture up due to the box being so large. There is no ground wire coming out of this metal box as well, and as you can see, there was a light bulb fixture from way back inside the box.

How do I install a new LED light fixture to this old junction box?

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's not a junction box.  That is a light fixture.  The bulb is screwed into that socket, and then the light is softened by a transparent cover that is part of the fixture. You can see the witness marks from the edge of the cover.

Comment: Looks more like a fixture/light box than a junction box.  Seems like the people just used the box to connect the wires also.